# Flask SQLalchemy order_by value joined from two Tables

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy

Currently I cant figure out how to perform a proper join in SQLalchemy, I have two tables `User` and `Room`each room is submited by a user and that is why each room has a `users_id` as `foreign key`.

User has an attribute `has_payed`.

What I want is to query all rooms which are in a certain city (works fine) and then order these results by the `User.has_payed` value. It shall show first all rooms which belong to users who have `has_payed == True`.

What I am currently doing:

```
Room.query.join(Room.users_id).order_by(User.has_payed)
```

That are my tables:

```
class User(UserMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(Text, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    has_payed = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    vorname = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    nachname = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    email_verified = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    handynummer = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    email = Column(Text, unique=True)
    # foreign key
    addresses = relationship('Room', back_populates="users")



class Room(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'zimmer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    art = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    personen = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    preis = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    infofeld = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    land = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    bundesland = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    stadt = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    plz = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    strasse = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    hausnr = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    zimmer_lat = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    zimmer_lng = Column(Float, nullable=False)

    # foreign key
    users_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    users = relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")
```

Comment: has_played is a boolean field.  you can't use order_by at this filed..

Comment: you can use this query - Room.query.join(Room.users_id).filter(User.has_payed==True)

Comment: It worked order_by a boolean value

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this solved the issue, but I dont know how it knows that it has to join on `Room.users_id == User.id`

```
Room.query.join(User).order_by(desc(User.has_payed))
```

Comment: you can use joinload